# Prove that $|f(z)| \leq M$ (alternative solution)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, maximum-principle

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

> [image]

Here is a solution given to me:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

I have the following questions:

1- Why specifically we defined $g$ like this? what is the intuition behind this definition?

2- Why we needed the closure of $\Omega$? i.e. $\bar{\Omega}$? I also can not see why from this construction we guarantee that $\lim sup_{n \to \infty}|g(z_n)| \leq |g(\bar{z})|$?

3- What is the main idea of this solution?

4- Is there a more succinct and elegant solution than this?

Could anyone help me answer these questions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $|f(z_0)|=M+\varepsilon, $ for $\varepsilon >0.$ Let $\Omega_0$ denote the connected component of $\Omega$ such that $z_0\in \Omega_0.$ There is $n_0$ satisfying   $0<{1\over n_0}<{\rm dist}(z_0,\partial \Omega_0).$ Let $$\Omega_n =\left\{z\in \Omega_0\,:\, {\rm dist}(z,\partial \Omega_0)>{1\over n} \right\}$$  Every set $\Omega_n$ is open and  $z_0\in \Omega_n$ for $n\ge n_0.$ Moreover $$\partial\Omega_n =\left\{z\in \Omega_0\,:\, {\rm dist}(z,\partial \Omega_0)={1\over n} \right\}$$ By the maximum modulus principle [(see related statement)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Formal_statement) there exists $z_n\in \partial \Omega_n,$ i.e. $$ {\rm dist}(z_n,\partial \Omega_0)={1\over n} $$ such that $|f(z_n)|\ge M+\varepsilon.$  By compactness of $\bar{\Omega}_0$ there is a convergent subsequence $z_{n_k},$ say to $z.$ Then $$|f(z_{n_k})|\ge M+\varepsilon,\quad z_{n_k}\to z\in \partial \Omega_0\subset \partial \Omega $$  hence $$\limsup |f(z_{n_k})|\ge M+\varepsilon >M$$ which gives a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "dist"?

Comment: what about my other questions?

Comment: "dist" denotes the distance from a point to a set. Try to visualize that for the open unit ball. I have concentrated on part $4 $ of your question, as it is hard to follow the proof attached to your question.

Comment: I did not get why you need the connected component $\Omega_0,$ could you explain this please?

Comment: Are you using the Archimedean property when you said there exists $n_0$? if so, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Are you using the maximum principle for Harmonic functions? is our function Harmonic?

Comment: Concerning connected component:  we get a contradiction considering the connected component  containing $z_0.$ So we do it because it is convenient.  For a positive number $a$ (in our case $a={\rm dist}(z_0, \partial \Omega_0)),$ there is a number $n_0$ so that ${1\over n_0}<a,$ namely $n_0>{1\over a}.$ All numbers greater than $n_0$ also satisfy ${1\over n}<a.$ We are using the maximum modulus principle for analytic functions, which follows easily from the Cauchy integral formula  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Formal_statement

Comment: Actually, I do not understand the part of the statement of the MM principle you are using in your proof (I usually use the statements in Conway " Functions of one complex variable " or "Complex Variables with applications" by S. Ponnusamy and Herb Silverman ), can you place restate this part of the statement? .... are you using the property that if the function does not attain its maximum then it will be unbounded? Is this sth said by the MM principle?

Comment: Also, I did not get exactly, what is the contradiction we reached?

Comment: why you said "We have $${\rm dist}\,(z_n,\partial\Omega_0)={1\over n}$$" could you clarify please?

Comment: I have re edited to clarify your last 3 comments

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I got your idea now but can you please recap it in words (the whole idea of the solution) not in mathematical symbols?

Comment: Sorry, but if we used the related statement as you said we should say tha $f$ attains a maximum  at the boundary i.e. $|f(z_n)| \leq M$ not  $|f(z_n)| \geq M + \epsilon$ as you said above, right?

Comment: The point $z_n$ belongs to $\partial\Omega_n$ not to $\partial \Omega_0.$ For example if $\Omega_0$ is the open unit ball then $\Omega_n$ is the open ball with radius $1-{1\over n}.$